# Integrating SnapKit with AWS Cognito - which standards does SK support?

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, snapchat

I'm trying to integrate SnapKit Login in my iOS app, and I'm using AWS as my backend - so I want to use Cognito.

Cognito User Pools can integrate third party login providers if they support OpenID Connect or SAML.

I can't find any documentation if SnapKit Login supports one of these. Is it OpenID Connect compliant? Does anyone know? If not, any suggestions on integrating SnapKit Login with AWS?

Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to solve it? I am facing the same issue, Snapchat docs are so messy